# argument list too long

Tags: linux, makefile

Ошибка появляется при попытке собрать ядро.
Тк я понял нужно что то поменять в makefile что-бы обойти MAX_ARG.
А что и как я не знаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть это значение через `getconf ARG_MAX`. На моей машине с гентой оно больше 2 миллионов, что должно с лихвой хватить. Поэтому, лучше уточнить, под что именно и на чем собираете ядро.

Comment: define legacy_ARG_MAX=131072 было.Прописал ulimit -s 9999999. Но всё так-же ошибка.

Comment: возможно ошибка то не в этом

Comment: Тогда не подскажите в чём может заключатся ошибка?Ps прикрепил скрин.

Comment: CentOS или RedHat? Печально. Насколько помню лечится только перекомпиляцией ядра с изменением #define MAX_ARG_PAGES (или установкой подходящего дистрибутива). ulimit не работает.

Comment: *`"This error means that the shell-expanded argument list is too long for a chunk of kernel memory reserved for (MAX_ARG_PAGES, usually something like 128KB, and specifically for the environment + command line and probably some other details), hard-coded in the kernel."'*